# Manage Bluetooth Communication

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Im actually trying to interact with a bluetooth module controlled by a microcontroller PIC.

So i need to build an android app in order to send caracters by bluetooth.

But im kind of lost.
The beginning is quiet clear to me ( enabling bluetooth and connect as client)

But i dont know how to interact with my Bluetooth Service class from my MainActivity.
How to interact with write and read.

I can see that im successfully Connected to my device.
ALEA is the name of the BT module i want to connect to.

Thanks for your help

```
package com.example.stef.bluetoothencore;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ArrayList<String> NomBT=null;
    BluetoothDevice mydevice;
    int position_alea=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listdevice);
        CheckBox Aleabox=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkAlea);

        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        NomBT= new ArrayList<String>();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }


        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = device;
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);  // On charge la liste de Device
                NomBT.add(device.getName().toString());
                if(device.getName().toString().equals("ALEA")){
                    mydevice=device;
                    Aleabox.setChecked(true);
                    Aleabox.setText(mydevice.getName().toString());
                }
            }

        }
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NomBT);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               // position_alea=i;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mydevice.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mydevice);
                 mConnectThread.start();
            }
        });

    }


    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private  final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }
        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
            mConnectedThread.write("c".getBytes());

        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int begin = 0;
            int bytes = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
                    for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                        if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
                            mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                            begin = i + 1;
                            if(i == bytes - 1) {
                                bytes = 0;
                                begin = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }


    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
            int end = (int)msg.arg2;

            switch(msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Up, im still blocked, i am connected to my device but i can't read or write data ...